# How to separate menu bar and ShellContent.Title in .NET Maui App?

Tags: desktop, maui

I'm testing the use of .NET Maui to write a desktop app. I learned how to create a menu bar, but when I run the app, the ShellContent.Title gets jammed onto the end of the menu so that it looks like an amateurishly emphasized menu item.

Is there any way to make the title appear above the menu, below the menu, or in the application's title bar?

[image: Image of sample application, showing how poorly placed ShellContent.Title is when you have a menu bar]

The code is basically what you get when you create the app, but I have modified two files:

AppShell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- AppShell.xaml -->
<Shell
    x:Class="SampleMauiApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleMauiApp"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

  <Shell.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label Text="Home" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
  </Shell.TitleView>

  <!-- Below I removed Title="Home" because it rendered in the page's menu bar -->
  <ShellContent
    ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
    Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleMauiApp.MainPage">

  <ContentPage.MenuBarItems>

    <MenuBarItem Text="File">
      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New" />
      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open..." />
      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit" />
    </MenuBarItem>

    <MenuBarItem Text="View">
      <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Change Location">
        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="New York, USA"
                        Command="{Binding ChangeLocationCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="NewYork" />
      </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Add Location"
                      Command="{Binding AddLocationCommand}" />
    </MenuBarItem>

    <MenuBarItem Text="Help">
      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="About..."/>
    </MenuBarItem>

  </ContentPage.MenuBarItems>

  <Grid IsClippedToBounds="True">
    <ScrollView>
      <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

      </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code/xaml

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a TitleView to customize.

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Home"  VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="Center"  FontSize="Large"   TextColor="Red" />
    </StackLayout>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: That sounded promising, but although it changes the text's styling, the title area still renders horizontally aligned with the menu bar. But thank you!

Comment: Could this be helpful [Can menu bar set in Caption\Title Bar? #7160](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7160) You could try using ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true